# why am i getting this error in my function when i try to update an object

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with this function:
arrayCheck, complete array:

```
[
    {
        "id1": {
            "var_1": "off",
            "val_1": "100"
        },
        "id2": {
            "var_2": "off",
            "val_2": "100"
        }
    }
]
```

in the function arrayCheck, indexArr, varName, valUpdate are all ok.
But returne "arrayCheck.forEach is not a function"

```
function updateArray(arrayCheck, indexArr, varName, valUpdate){
    arrayCheck.forEach(obj => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            if (key === indexArr) {
                obj[indexArr][varName] = valUpdate;
            }
        });
    });
    return arrayCheck;
}
```

Please can anyone help me

Comment: All of that code is fine - I put it in a snippet and it tested fine. Can u show how you invoke the function?

Comment: ```var indexArray = 'id2';
var varName = 'var_2';
var valUpdate = 'new_value';

var myarray = [
    {
        "id1": {
            "var_1": "off",
            "val_1": "100"
        },
        "id2": {
            "var_2": "off",
            "val_2": "100"
        }
    }
];

updateArray(myarray, indexArray, varName, valUpdate);```

Comment: sorry i don't know to paste perfect the code

Answer (score 0):

You're updating your array in the function but not assigning it back to the original afterwards, just set the value, like

```
array = updateArray(array, 'id2', 'var_2', 'John');
```

```js
let array = [
    {
        "id1": {
            "var_1": "off",
            "val_1": "100"
        },
        "id2": {
            "var_2": "off",
            "val_2": "100"
        }
    }
]
 
function updateArray(arrayCheck, indexArr, varName, valUpdate){
    arrayCheck.forEach(obj => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
            if (key === indexArr) {
                obj[indexArr][varName] = valUpdate;
            }
        });
    });
    return arrayCheck;
}

array = updateArray(array, 'id2', 'var_2', 'John');
console.log(array)
```

Comment: I found where the error was, in the code of the function that returned the array I had put myArray[0].  Thanks everyone for the big help